# Specific format/formula when changing column datatype

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, datatypes, alter-table

Can one modify a column's datatype using a very specific conversion format?

For example, when converting from `datetime` to `varchar` I'd like to use the `yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss` format, *not the system default* which is `109` I believe.

Is there any way to achieve this without creating a temporary column?

Comment: @McNets that question you linked has a "sorry, not possible" as the accepted answer, how is that a duplicate?

Comment: Why not change the column to [datetime2(0)](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/160713/22336) instead?

Comment: Why do you want to do this? You will lose the original datetime column and make the data much harder to work with. I would rather format it in the application or create a computed column with the converted value or something. It's not clear what you want to accomplish by doing this. Unlike for example postgres an alter column doesn't have a using so I'm afraid if you really want to do this your best option is to create a new column, write the data using an update, and remove the old column.

Comment: @TomV-trytopanswers.xyz the datetime bit was "for example" I'm actually converting `sql_variant` to make it deterministic.

Answer (score 1):

First and foremost:

- Why are you storing dates as text?

Second, as I pointed out in comments, there is an [accepted answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/100990/110455) of [Aaron Bertrand](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/1186/aaron-bertrand) that states: 'Sorry, not possible', you cannot change the default conversion behaviour. And that is why I flagged this question as duplicated.

And third, having a look at Microsoft SQL Server 2008 Internals, at chapter: Internals of Altering Tables. (bold is mine)

> Another negative side effect of altering tables happens **when a
>   column is altered to increase its length**. In this case, **the old
>   column is not actually replaced**. Rather, **a new column is added to
>   the table**, and DBCC PAGE shows you that the old data is still there.
>   I’ll let you explore the page dumps for this situation on your own,
>   but we can see some of this unexpected behaviour by just looking at the
>   column offsets using the column detail query that I showed you earlier
>   in this chapter.
>
> Another drawback to the behaviour of SQL Server in not actually dropping the old column is that we are now more severely limited in the size of the row. **The row size now includes the old column**, which is no longer usable or visible (unless you use DBCC PAGE).

You can check the length by using DATALENGTH function:

```
DECLARE @dt datetime = GETDATE();
DECLARE @sdt varchar(20) = CONVERT(varchar, GETDATE(), 20);

SELECT @dt AS dt, DATALENGTH(@dt) AS dt_lenght,
       @sdt AS sdt, DATALENGTH(@sdt) AS sdt_lenght
GO
```

```
dt                      | dt_length | sdt                 | sdt_length
:---------------------- | --------: | :------------------ | ---------:
2020-05-30 10:50:51.587 |         8 | 2020-05-30 10:50:51 |         19
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=3e7a75616e53217bd9744c54ac176d19)*

Comment: "Why are you storing dates as text" well, it's more complicated than that. It's actually `sql_variant`, b/c the database uses "Entity-Attribute-Value" pattern for UDF (user-defined-fields) and I need to make that UDF data searchable via FT-index. But I can't create an indexed view from sql_variant (b/c its non deterministic) so I'm actually converting UDF to strings from sql_variant

Comment: @jitbit check [this very similar question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/193112/22336) and convert to datetime2 instead - by the same McNets mind you ;)

Comment: @jitbit then I think this should be the question. According Aaron you  can't alter the default cast behaviour.